# Is there a way to insert Latex directly into a PDF?

Tags: pdf, latex

Is there a way to insert formatted Latex directly into a PDF? I know I can convert it to an image file and then inset or paste the image into a PDF (using Adobe Acrobat Pro), but I would like to skip that if possible. Is there a plugin or software I could use?

Thank you.